# How to make a new object from selecting some data from existing object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a json object as follows.

```
[{
 "id": "1",
   "username": "vishnu",
 "FromDate": "Thu Apr 21 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
  "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
  "task": "fixing bugs",
  "time": "1"
  }, {

    "id": "2",
   "username": "vishnu",
  "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
   "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
   "task": "working on ui of creatwhimsy home page",
    "time": "2"
       }, {
         "id": "3",
     "username": "vishnu",
   "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
      "selectedProject": "bigiron",
      "task": "working on api",
     "time": "5" 
       }, {
     "id": "4",
   "username": "vishnu",
     "FromDate": "Sat Jul 30 2016 12:03:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time",
     "selectedProject": "timetracker",
     "task": "working on ui of creatwhimsy home page and admin side home      page",
     "time": "1"
  }, {
       "id": "5",
      "username": "vishnu",
       "FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
       "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
   "task": "fixing bugs",
    "time": "1"
   }]
```

Let the object name be Data. I want to make a new object fro Data, but it should only contain "selectedProject" and "time".
How to do that in angularjs?

Comment: What u have tried so far?

Comment: Iterate through the list, and pick the wanted object based(append to new list) on the condition you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate and create a new object with desire data. For this you can use javascript [push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) function.
what you need to do is

```
$scope.log = [];
angular.forEach($scope.names, function(value, key){  
   $scope.log.push({"selectedProject":value.selectedProject,"time":value.time});
});
```

Here is JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyaqzgo6/4/

A sample code for you:

```
<script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.names = [{
                        "id": "1",
                        "username": "vishnu",
                        "FromDate": "Thu Apr 21 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                        "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
                        "task": "fixing bugs",
                        "time": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "2",
                        "username": "vishnu",
                        "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                        "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
                        "task": "working on ui of creatwhimsy home page",
                        "time": "2"
                    }, {
                        "id": "3",
                        "username": "vishnu",
                        "FromDate": "Wed Mar 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                        "selectedProject": "bigiron",
                        "task": "working on api",
                        "time": "5"
                    }, {
                        "id": "4",
                        "username": "vishnu",
                        "FromDate": "Sat Jul 30 2016 12:03:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time",
                        "selectedProject": "timetracker",
                        "task": "working on ui of creatwhimsy home page and admin side home      page",
                        "time": "1"
                    }, {
                        "id": "5",
                        "username": "vishnu",
                        "FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
                        "selectedProject": "createwhimsy",
                        "task": "fixing bugs",
                        "time": "1"
                    }];
                $scope.log = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.names, function(value, key){
                    $scope.log.push({"selectedProject":value.selectedProject,"time":value.time});
                });
                console.log($scope.log);

            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function SomeFunction() {

 function getdata(callback, url) {

    var obj= {};
    $http.get(url).success(function(response) {

        if (response.jsonname[0].length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.jsonname[0].length; i++) {   
                obj= {
                    selectedProject:response.jsonname[0][i].selectedProject,  
                    time:response.jsonname[0][i].time

                }

            }
        } else {

        }
    }).error(function() {
        //something        
    }).then(function() {
        callback(obj);
    });;
}
return {
    getdata: getdata
}
```

}